# Remove unset array containing specific string

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the following array imported from a CSV:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => QUARTERLY STATS;Q1/2011;Q2/2011;Q3/2011;Q4/2011;Q1/2012;Q2/2012;Q3/2012;Q4/2012;Q1/2013;Q2/2013;Q3/2013;Q4/2013;Q1/2014
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => January;7500;8800;9500;10000;10500;11000;11500;12000;12500;13000;13420;13820;14200
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => ;;17
        [1] => 30%;8%;5
        [2] => 30%;5%;4
        [3] => 80%;4
        [4] => 50%;4
        [5] => 30%;4
        [6] => 20%;4%;3
        [7] => 20%;3%;2
        [8] => 70%
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => TOTAL;7500;8500;9500;11000;12500;11400;11800;13000;12500;13000;13420;13820;14200
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => ;;17
        [1] => 30%;7
        [2] => 95%;5
        [3] => 26%;5%;4
        [4] => 76%;4
        [5] => 55%;4
        [6] => 35%;4
        [7] => 17%;4%;3
        [8] => 23%;2
        [9] => 98%;2
        [10] => 75%
    )
```

So,

I would like to get rid of all arrays containing "% and TOTAL".

I thought to loop through and unset the matching case:

$remove ="TOTAL";
foreach ($csv as $key => $value){

```
if (in_array($remove,$value[$key])){
unset($value[$key]);
```

}
}

This is the error I got:
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

My PHP Version 5.3.10

Would you do it that way or would you use the array_filter?

I am browsing since 2 hours the forum but I could not find any hint helping me out.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by `preg_replace` for removing  `TOTAL` & `%`. If you want to remove the element from `array` then use `unset` & finally use `array_filter` for removing `null` elements.

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    foreach($value as $k=>$v){
        $newArr[$key][$k] = preg_replace('/(TOTAL)|(%)/', '', $v); //for removing TOTAL & %
        unset($arr[$key][$k]); //for unset the array elements that contains TOTAL & %
    }
}

//Output by replacement
print '<pre>';
print_r($newArr);
print '</pre>';

//output after using unset
print '<pre>';
print_r(array_filter($arr));
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in which is in print_r(array_filter($arr)); 


$newArr = $csv; foreach($arr as $key=>$value){ 
foreach($value as $k=>$v){ $newArr[$key][$k] = preg_replace('/(TOTAL)|(%)/', '', $v); //for removing TOTAL & % 
unset($arr[$key][$k]); //for unset the array elements that contains TOTAL & % } } //Output by replacement 

print '<pre>'; print_r($newArr); 
print '</pre>'; //output after using unset 
print '<pre>'; 
print_r(array_filter($arr)); print '</pre>';


Do I have some PHP Version issue? My Version is 5.3.0

Comment: I think you misunderstood. `$arr` is original `array`. Assign `$arr` after reading the `CSV` file. `array_filter()` need an `array`. May be you given a `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

In your case:

```
foreach ($csv as $subArray)
{
    for ($i = 0, $len = count($subArray); $i < $len; $i++)
    {
        if (strpos($subArray[$i], $remove) !== false)
            unset($subArray[$i])
    }
}
```

Comments:

1. strict comparasion for strpos, if we use !=, then 0 position would be equals to false.
2. inner loop is "for-loop" bevause it's better to avoid changing content of array inside foreach.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr[][] = ("QUARTERLY STATS;Q1/2011;Q2/2011;Q3/2011;Q4/2011;Q1/2012;Q2/2012;Q3/2012;Q4/2012;Q1/2013;Q2/2013;Q3/2013;Q4/2013;Q1/2014");
$arr[][] = ("January;7500;8800;9500;10000;10500;11000;11500;12000;12500;13000;13420;13820;14200");
$arr[] = array(";;17","30%;8%;5","30%;5%;4","80%;4","50%;4","30%;4","20%;4%;3","20%;3%;2","70%");
$arr[][] = ("TOTAL;7500;8500;9500;11000;12500;11400;11800;13000;12500;13000;13420;13820;14200");
$arr[] = array("30%;7","95%;5","26%;5%;4","76%;4","55%;4","35%;4","17%;4%;3","23%;2","98%;2","75%");

$newArr = array();
    foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {
        foreach($value as $k=>$v) {
        $newArr[$key][$k] = preg_replace('/(TOTAL)|(%)/', '', $v); //for removing TOTAL & %
        unset($arr[$key][$k]); //for unset the array elements that contains TOTAL & %
    }
    unset($arr[$key]); // IT does not unset ARR[2] ARR[3] and ARR[4] containing TOTAL & %
}
```

Output by replacement

```
print '<pre>';
print_r($newArr);
print '</pre>';
```

Output after using unset

```
print '<pre>';
print_r(array_filter($arr));
print '</pre>';
```

I did create exactly the same ARRAY as imported from CSV.
unset does not unset ARRAY2,3,4 which is containing TOTAL AND %.
unset does not unset ARRAY2,3,4 which is containing TOTAL AND %.